# Responsive Email signature mobile

Tags: html, email, html-email

I tried to make an email signature in HTML. But I want to make it responsive on small screens like smartphones.
My question is how to place the tables below each other.
[Current signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L68w8.jpg) ---
[The signature I want on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlMtX.jpg)

I made the signature out of tables with a table generator, but I'm stuck at this point.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Signature</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 1286px; height: 292px;" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: black;" "="" 235.867px;="" text-align:=""

            center;="" background-color:="" white;"="">
            <div style="   background-color: transparent; text-align: center;">
              <h1><span style="font-size:40px;"><b><span style="font-family: Roboto;"><span

                        style="color: #d6d752;">Lorem </span><span style="color: white;">Ipsum<br>
                      </span></span></b></span></h1>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: white;"><span style="font-family: Roboto;">Function</span></span><br>
              <span style="color: white;"><span style="font-family: Roboto;"> </span></span><br>
              <span style="color: white;"><span style="font-family: Roboto;">
                  Company</span></span></div>
          </td>
          <td><img src="file://contact%20-%203.png"

              alt="contact"><br>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 327.233px;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"> </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;"><br>
                </span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Phone</span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Phone</span></div>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;"><br>
                </span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">website</span></div>
              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
              <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">website</span></div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #c6c6c6; text-align: center; width: 516.5px;"><img

              src="file://20NW%20350-%201.jpg"

              alt="logo"><br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your best bet will be to make it hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this helpful guide: [github - Email-Framework](https://github.com/g13nn/Email-Framework)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Signature</title>
  
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
    
   

    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img { border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
    body { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: inherit !important;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      font-weight: inherit !important;
      line-height: inherit !important;
    }
   .box {
    min-height: 200px;
   }
    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }

    /* MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media all and (max-width:639px){ 
      .wrapper{ width:320px!important; padding: 0 !important; }
      .container{ width:300px!important;  padding: 0 !important; }
      .mobile{ width:300px!important; display:block!important; padding: 0 !important; }
      .img{ width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }
      *[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
      *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height:none !important; }
    }

  </style>    
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#F2F2F2;">
  
  <span style="display: block; width: 640px !important; max-width: 640px; height: 1px" class="mobileOff"></span>
  
  <center>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            
         

        
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
             <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">

                <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="200" class="mobile box" align="center" valign="top" style="background-color: black; text-align:center; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
                      <h1 style="font-size: 25px; color: #d6d752; padding-top: 50px">Lorem <span style="color: #ffffff;">Ipsum</span></h1>
       <h2 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px;">Function</h2>
       <h2 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px;">Company</h2>   
        
                      </td>
                      <td width="200" class="mobile" align="center" valign="top">
                       <div style="display:inline-block;">
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Adress</span></div>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;"><br>
            </span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Phone</span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">Phone</span></div>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;"><br>
            </span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">website</span></div>
          <span style="font-family: Poppins;"> </span>
          <div><span style="font-family: Poppins;">website</span></div>
        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="200" class="mobile box" align="center" valign="top" style="background-color: #c6c6c6; text-align: center;">
                       <img src="file://20NW%20350-%201.jpg" alt="logo">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


          
            
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```